# how to deal with this distribution ??

Tags: definite-integrals, distribution-theory

in the sense of distribution how do i calculate the following integral

$$ \int _{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{|x-a|} $$

I saw something like this

$$ \int _{0}^{a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{|x-a|}+ \int _{a}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{|x-a|}$$

but not sure about this split of the integration limits and if the integration limits are correct, is this valid also when $ a=0 4 4 thanks.

Comment: It appears from your second formula that $a\gt0$. Is that true? If $a\ge0$, and $f(a)\ne0$, the integral may not even converge.

Comment: It looks as if you should not have an abs value in the denominator. In that case, the question makes (more) sense.